# list files in terminal with spaces

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, ls

```
ls -1 | grep -v images | xargs rm -r
```

That does not delete files that have spaces in them. How can I include them? Is there a way when I say ls that it displays with spaces escaped?

Comment: `find . ! -name '*images*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r`

Answer (score 4):

ls has the **-Q** option to quote them. You then simply can do this:

```
ls -Q | grep -v images | xargs rm -r
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can make this work with `ls(1)`, I think a better approach is to use `find(1)` instead:

```
find . \! -name '*images*' -exec rm -r {} \;
```

or

```
find . \! -name '*images*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r
```

I prefer the `-print0 | xargs -0` approach when it works, because `xargs(1)` will spawn only as many `rm(1)` commands as is necessary. When you've only got 200 files, 200 executions or one execution won't make much difference, but if you had 10,000 files to delete, you'd really rather execute `rm(1)` only 200 or 500 times rather than all 10,000 times.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
ls -1 | grep -v images | xargs -I {} rm -r "{}"
```